# Query optimizing How to

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my script I pass Object `ID` as querystring parameter. like `?idobject=1962`

Now first I have to access from the `OBJECTS` table the `GeoLat` and `GeoLng` columns
and I have to check again if there are other objects containing the same `Geo Data`

```
SELECT GeoLng, GeoLat
FROM OBJECTS
WHERE ID = 1962
```

from above query I have to read the `GeoLng` and `GeoLat` variables and have to write the second query as follows

```
SELECT O.ID
FROM OBJECTS O
WHERE GeoLng = '12.72812515' /* will be taken from above query */
AND GeoLat   = '47.7794388' /* will be taken from above query */

AND EXISTS(
    SELECT ID 
    FROM InfObjects 
    WHERE ID = O.ID
    )
```

Can I write these 2 queries into a single query?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated based on Rich's comment.

What you need is a self-join.

```
SELECT O2.ID
FROM OBJECTS O1
JOIN OBJECTS O2 on O1.GeoLng = O2.GeoLng AND O1.GeoLat = O2.GeoLng
WHERE O1.ID = 1962   
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT ID 
    FROM InfObjects 
    WHERE ID = O2.ID
)
```

Or even more efficiently, like this:

```
SELECT O2.ID
FROM OBJECTS O1
JOIN OBJECTS O2 on O1.GeoLng = O2.GeoLng AND O1.GeoLat = O2.GeoLng
JOIN InfObjects I ON O2.ID = I.ID
WHERE O1.ID = 1962
```

Comment: The result of the second query is all rows with the same GeoLong and GeoLat as the row with the given ID, not just the one row with the given ID.

Comment: Shouldn't the `ID` part of `WHERE ID = 1962` be qualified, so as not to be ambiguous?

Comment: Yep, I noticed that just as you were commenting. I had qualified it in the first query but not in the second. Thanks!

Comment: Both SELECTs should probably be `SELECT O2.ID ...`. The second one should also alias the first `OBJECTS` as `O1`, not `O` (or the references should be changed accordingly).

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks again. Maybe I shouldn't be giving programming solutions before 9am on a Monday...

Answer (score 3):

Staying with the "EXISTS" expressions, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT O.ID
FROM OBJECTS O
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM InfObjects 
    WHERE ID = O.ID
)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM OBJECTS o2
    WHERE o2.GeoLng = O.GeoLng AND o2.GeoLat = O.GeoLat AND o2.ID = 1962
)
```

You could also do it with an inner join instead of a correlated query, but I think this syntax should produce a sufficiently performant query as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT O.ID
FROM OBJECTS OID
INNER JOIN Objects O ON O.GeoLng = OID.GeoLng AND O.GeoLat = OID.GeoLat
WHERE OID.ID = 1962
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT ID 
    FROM InfObjects 
    WHERE ID = OID.ID
    )
```